# pygame.error: Out of memory?

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy intentado crear un juego "space invaders" con pygame. Voy recopilando información de varias fuentes de la web para llegar al objetivo final. El caso es que, ahora mismo el juego corre, funciona todo, excepto porque cuando lleva un rato en ejecución, me indica el siguiente error "pygame.error: Out of memory". No se como proceder. Realmente alterna entre dos errores, porque también me indica a veces "error con la lectura de archivo png". Agradezco una ayuda.
Mi código tiene 238 líneas, pongo aquí la parte que creo que puede estar dando el error.

```
def creacion_enemigos():
        global enemigo_state
        global i
        global enemigos_vidas
        global golpes
        global jugador_y
        global laser_y
        global lives

        if enemigo_state is "ready":
            for i in (numero_enemigos):
                x = random.randint(0,
                                   2)  ##funcion para que aparezcan naves enemigas de distinto color "de forma aleatoria"
                if x is 0:
                    enemigoImg.append(
                        pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_red_small.png")).convert_alpha())
                elif x is 1:
                    enemigoImg.append(
                        pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_blue_small.png")).convert_alpha())
                elif x is 2:
                    enemigoImg.append(
                        pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_green_small.png")).convert_alpha())
```

Comment: en lugar de llamar a load cada vez que creas un enemigo, ¿por qué no cargas todas las imágenes una única vez y las reutilizas? Creo que ése es el origen de tu problema, estás creado multitud de copias de cada imagen, ocupando toda la memoria

Comment: No había caído en ese detalle. Ahora ya esta solventado, realizo una única carga fuera del bucle. Gracias por el aporte!!